# completion handler for scene2d actions

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

Is there a completion handler for scene2d actions we can use? I would like to trigger additional code when action ends. I found this function, but there is probably a more robust way of getting notified when action ends.

```
float delay = 1; // seconds

Timer.schedule(new Task(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your work
    }
}, delay);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [SequenceAction](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/SequenceAction.html):

The following example creates an `Action` that move an `Actor` to `(5, 5)` and then runs whatever is in the `Runnable`:

```
SequenceAction sequenceAction = Actions.sequence(Actions.moveTo(5, 5), Actions.run(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // When this runs, that means the previous Action is complete. 
    }
}));
```